# how to automatically update content shown in lightning component

Tags: apex, trigger, lightning-aura-components

I have a lightning component that will display top 5 recently updated/inserted opportunities.

Whenever an opportunity is created I want that to be shown in my lightning APP without any event(ex: Click). Kindly advise how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use Andrew Fawcett's [Streaming API component](https://github.com/afawcett/streamingcomponent) to be notified of new records. No external events would be necessary. You'll need to read more about the [Streaming API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/intro_stream.htm) documentation.